# Regex to match specific pattern

Tags: php, regex

I am so bad at creating regex and I'm struggling with what I am SURE it's a simple stupid regex.

I am using PHP to do this match. Here is what I have until now.

```
Test string: 8848842356063003
if(!preg_match('/^[0-2]|[7-9]{16}/', $token)) {
    return array('status' => 'failed', 'message' => "Invalid token", 'token' => '');
}
```

The regex must comply to this: Start with 0-2 or 7-9 and have EXACTLY 16 characters. What am I doing wrong? Because I get, as a match:

```
array(
  0 => 8
)
```

And I should get:

```
array(
  0 => 8848842356063003
)
```

By the way: I am using [PHP Live Regex](http://www.phpliveregex.com/) to test my regex string.

Thanks in advance,
Ares D.

Comment: You should read about [subpatterns](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The regex must comply to this: Start with 0-2 or 7-9 and have EXACTLY 16 characters

You can put starting numbers in same character class and use end anchor after matching 15 more charaters:

```
/^[0-27-9].{15}$/
```

If you want to match only digits then use:

```
/^[0-27-9]\d{15}$/
```

Comment: PERFECT! THANK YOU! I don't know why I'm not getting this stupid regex stuff :( Is there a good book/tutorial that you can recommend?

Comment: I know that one... Unfortunately, there aren't that much examples for me to go with, so that I can understand fully. But thanks allot :) You have been more than helpful. I appreciate it, sir!